# How to calculate loss in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I've simple model like this:

```
n_input = 14 
n_out   = 1 

weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_out]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_out]))
}
def perceptron(input_tensor, weights, biases):
    out_layer_multiplication = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights['out'])
    out_layer_addition = out_layer_multiplication + biases['out']
    return out_layer_addition

input_tensor = rows
model = perceptron
```

"rows" dimension is (N, 14) and "out" dimension is (N), where "out" is result of running model with "rows" as "input_tensor".

And I want to calculate loss in tensorflow. Algorythm of calculating is:

```
ls = 0
for i in range(len(out)-1):
    if out[i] < out[i+1]:
        ls += 1
```

Where "ls" is model loss. How can I calculate it in tensorflow notation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
l = out.get_shape()[0]
a = out[0:l-1]
b = out[1:l]
c = tf.where(a<b, tf.ones_like(a), tf.zeros_like(a))
return tf.reduce_sum(c)
```

In practice, `a` contains `out[i]` and `b` contains `out[i+1]`. `c` has 1s every time `out[i]<out[i+1]`. So summing them is equal to make a +1 each time.